# VB.net animated alphablend control on painted panel

Tags: vb.net, animation, alphablending

A want use alphablend animated controls on painted panel or other controls, but my code is not working 100%.
My code is now flickering the animation.
If I set doublebuffered variable to true, my controls background replacing to black.
If I use Me.Invalidate() instead of Parent.Invalidate my animated painting is very bugs.

```
Imports System.Reflection

Public Class Form1
    Private Sub FlowLayoutPanel1_Paint(sender As Object, e As PaintEventArgs)
        Dim TheControl As Control = CType(sender, Control)
        Dim oRAngle As Rectangle = New Rectangle(0, 0, TheControl.Width, TheControl.Height)
        Dim oGradientBrush As Brush = New Drawing.Drawing2D.LinearGradientBrush(oRAngle, Color.White, Color.SteelBlue, Drawing.Drawing2D.LinearGradientMode.ForwardDiagonal)
        e.Graphics.FillRectangle(oGradientBrush, oRAngle)
    End Sub
    Public Shared Sub DoubleBufferedSet(ByVal dgv As Object, ByVal setting As Boolean)
        Dim dgvType As Type = dgv.[GetType]()
        Dim pi As PropertyInfo = dgvType.GetProperty("DoubleBuffered", BindingFlags.Instance Or BindingFlags.NonPublic)
        pi.SetValue(dgv, setting, Nothing)
    End Sub
    Private Sub FlowLayoutPanel1_Resize(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
        sender.Invalidate()
    End Sub
    Dim flowlayoutpanel1 As New FlowLayoutPanels
    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        flowlayoutpanel1.Dock = DockStyle.Fill
        AddHandler flowlayoutpanel1.Paint, AddressOf FlowLayoutPanel1_Paint
        AddHandler flowlayoutpanel1.Resize, AddressOf FlowLayoutPanel1_Resize
        Me.Controls.Add(flowlayoutpanel1)
        DoubleBufferedSet(flowlayoutpanel1, True)
        Dim testc1 As New OpaqControl
        testc1.Size = New Size(300, 100)
        flowlayoutpanel1.Controls.Add(testc1)
        Dim testc2 As New OpaqControl
        testc2.Size = New Size(300, 100)
        flowlayoutpanel1.Controls.Add(testc2)
    End Sub
End Class
Public Class OpaqControl
    Inherits Control
    Private Timer1 As New Timer()
    Dim up As Boolean = True
    Dim poss As Integer = 1
    Public Sub New()
        'DoubleBuffered = True
        AddHandler Timer1.Tick, AddressOf TickHandler
        Me.Timer1.Interval = 10
    End Sub
    Protected Sub TickHandler(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
        If up Then
            poss += 2
            If poss >= 80 Then Me.Timer1.Enabled = False
        Else
            poss -= 2
            If poss <= 0 Then Me.Timer1.Enabled = False
        End If
        Parent.Invalidate(New Rectangle(Me.Location, Me.Size), True)
        'Me.Invalidate()
    End Sub
    Protected Overrides Sub OnMouseEnter(e As EventArgs)
        up = True
        Me.Timer1.Enabled = True
        MyBase.OnMouseEnter(e)
    End Sub
    Protected Overrides Sub OnMouseLeave(e As EventArgs)
        up = False
        Me.Timer1.Enabled = True
        MyBase.OnMouseLeave(e)
    End Sub
    Protected Overrides ReadOnly Property CreateParams() As CreateParams
        Get
            Dim cp As CreateParams = MyBase.CreateParams
            cp.ExStyle = cp.ExStyle Or &H20
            Return cp
        End Get
    End Property
    Protected Overrides Sub OnPaintBackground(pevent As PaintEventArgs)
    End Sub
    Protected Overrides Sub OnPaint(e As PaintEventArgs)
        e.Graphics.FillRectangle(New SolidBrush(Color.FromArgb(50, 0, 100, 255)), New Rectangle(0, 0, 300, 100))
        e.Graphics.FillRectangle(New SolidBrush(Color.FromArgb(50, 0, 0, 0)), New Rectangle(0, 100 - poss, 300, 80))
        e.Graphics.DrawString("Test", Font, Brushes.Yellow, New Point(100, 100 - poss))
    End Sub
End Class
```

Sorry for my bad english.
Please try my code (with try remove apostrophe) for understand my problems.

I use VB 2015.
I no want use any thirdparty dlls.
I no want use WPF.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It flickers badly because you can see the Parent painting itself.  Double-buffering is required to get rid of that artifact.  Do *not* use WS_EX_TRANSPARENT, that defeats double-buffering.  The Control class already supports transparency well, take advantage of that feature like this:

```
Public Sub New()
    Me.DoubleBuffered = True
    Me.SetStyle(ControlStyles.SupportsTransparentBackColor, True)
    Me.BackColor = Color.Transparent
    AddHandler Timer1.Tick, AddressOf TickHandler
    Me.Timer1.Interval = 10
End Sub
```

Delete the CreateParams() and OnPaintBackground() overrides.  Call Me.Invalidate() instead of Parent.Invalidate().  And it is silky-smooth.